# reselect createSelector type definitions for a redux store

Tags: typescript, redux, reselect

I have the following state type for my redux reducer:

```
export interface CharactersState {
  characters: CharacterType[];
  error: string | null;
  isFetching: boolean;
}
```

I am then using this state type with combineReducer to create my store:

```
const initialState: CharactersState = {
  characters: [],
  error: null,
  isFetching: true // initiated with fetching true on app load
};

const characters = (state = initialState, action: CharacterActionsType) => {
  switch (action.type) {
   // commented out reducer logic here since it is not relevant
   //...

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  characters
});

export type RootStateType = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export default rootReducer;
```

I am then using this rootReducer in a component controller:

```
const getCharacters = (state: RootStateType): CharactersState =>
  state.characters;

export const makeCharactersList = createSelector<
  RootStateType,
  CharactersState,
  CharacterListType[]
>(getCharacters, characters => {
  return characters.characters
    .map(character => {
      return {
        _id: character._id,
        name: character.name,
        description: character.description
      };
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
    });
});

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootStateType) => {
  return {
    characters: makeCharactersList(state)
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    handleDeleteClick: (_id: string | null) => {
      dispatch(postDeleteCharacter(_id));
    }
  };
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

export default connector(CharacterSidebar);
```

The controller is rendered in the parent component without passing any props:

```
<Sidebar />
```

How do I write the correct type definition for `makeCharactersList`? It seems that `createSelector` should take the types of State, OwnProps, ConnectedProps - in my case it seems that OwnProps would just be an empty object?

But when I set the type definition to:

```
createSelector<
  RootStateType,
 {},
  CharacterListType[]
```

I get the following error:

> Property 'characters' does not exist on type '{}'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple overloads for `createSelector`, but the one that you are matching is this:

```
export function createSelector<S, R1, T>(
  selector: (state: S) => R,
  combiner: (res: R1) => T,
): OutputSelector<S, T, (res: R1) => T>;
```

The three generics are:

1. `S` - the type of the root state - `RootStateType`
2. `R1` - the value selected by the first selector, which is also the input for the combiner - `CharactersState`
3. `T` - the value that you return from the combiner - `Pick<CharacterType, '_id' | 'name' | 'description'>[]` (an array of characters with only the selected properties)

Probably your `CharacterListType` is an alias for the picked properties in #3?  If so, then you had it correct in your code block.

```
export const makeCharactersList = createSelector<
  RootStateType,
  CharactersState,
  CharacterListType[]
>(getCharacters, characters => {
...
```